# Can Disguise Self be cast on someone other than you?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells

Can [Disguise Self](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/disguise-self) be cast on somebody else in some way, or only on yourself? Is there another spell that acts similarly that can be cast on somebody else?

([Polymorph](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/polymorph) seems more extreme than I am looking for. I'm looking for an effective magical disguise rather than a change of essence.)

Comment: Wouldn't that make it "Disguise Other?"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

## No

*Disguise Self* is only for you, but [Seeming](https://www.dndbeyond.com/spells/seeming) (5th level) may be what you're looking for.

> This spell allows you to change the appearance of any number of creatures that you can see within range

Answer (score 6):

**No**

Disguise self has a range of 'self', which means it cannot be cast on anyone other than yourself.

PHB, page 233 right underneath the title.

> Range: Self